# spring prototype beans vs prototype lazy-init beans performance comparison

Tags: java, spring

What is the benefit of using lazy-init=true prototype beans vs non-lazy-init prototype beans? What is the best practices and more preferred solution? Will I get significant performance boost using lazy init prototype beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferred is either opinion or based on your use case.

Both will perform well enough so they won't be the bottleneck in your code.  If there's a performance issue, it'll be caused something that you've done, not Spring.

The only reason to prefer lazy is if the cost of initialization is prohibitively high and there's a good chance that you won't use that object.

If you're *certain* to use it, then I see little reason for lazy init.  You have to pay the cost sometime; pay it right away on startup with eager init and sleep at night.

This is a nano-optimization that rarely pays off.